# Augmenting an existing Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, configure, autoconf

I'm working on an existing program that depends on a C library, an a rather old one actually, that simply has a `Makefile` and a `README` file that has some instructions to modify the makefile to compile successfully on different systems. I've been tasked with cleaning the program's build process up so it's portable without hacking makefiles etc, so this means ensuring the C library is portable.

One thing that needs to be done on recent versions of `MacOS` for example is defining `SIZEOF_VOID_P` correctly, because it defaults to `4` if undefined which naturally causes horrific segfaults on 64bit systems. I've just defined this in the Makefile as 8 but obviously now I've broken it for 32bit systems.

My thoughts were initially just to write a C file that's output that has some `#ifdef`s that spit out the appropriate defines if they're missing an prepend that output to the existing makefile, but it seems a bit hacky. Standard configure scripts seem to do all this themselves anyway, so I thought why not use them. I read that configure scripts can be generated with `autoconf`, but I don't want to trash the existing makefiles (which I fear may cause more problems than it solves). I just want to add appropriate some defines to them.

Is there a nice why do to this?

Comment: Change the code so it uses `sizeof(void*)` instead of `SIZEOF_VOID_P`?

Comment: The C library isn't mine, I'd rather not hack up all of its code when I could just define the macro correctly.

Comment: If it's old and unmaintained you might as well take over your copy of it (assuming it's open source). The main problem with using customized versions of libraries is you might find it difficult to merge your changes with upstream changes, but if there is no upstream then you don't have that problem. (You also can't distribute them as .so files because the user might have a different non-customized version)

Comment: The example I gave is not the only issue, hence the question about configure scripts.

Comment: Where are these definitions presently coming from? Is the makefile providing them, or are they in a header?

Comment: In a number of headers. Around 6. They all seem to just define SIZEOF_VOID_P = 4 is it's not defined, which is silly I know.

But like I said, this is supposed to be a more general question, and there are heaps of different Makefile options for different systems, just listed in the Makefile and commented.

Comment: You are only troubled by that one macro. Using `autoconf` and `automake` just to handle that one macro is an overkill. You can simply insert at the top of Makefile something like `SIZEOF_VOID_P:=$(shell uname -m | grep -q x86_64 && echo 8 || echo 4)` then pass this to `CFLAGS` like `CFLAGS:=-DSIZEOF_VOID_P=$(SIZEOF_VOID_P) ...`.

Comment: I'm troubled by lots of things, the macro was just one example. The makefile currently is a mess of options for different systems.

Comment: If your time budget allows, I recommend to clean the things up. If not, I would make a strong case for the management to allocate that budget. For from what I read in your question, you'd face lot more (and lot more serious) problems by blindly taking this mess for granted.

Answer (score 1):

If `autoconf`, `cmake`, or similar programs are not an option you can do something that is similar to your own idea.

```sh
CC=gcc

.PHONY: all

all: main

pre-build:
        $(CC) constants.c -o constants
        $(eval SIZEOF_VOID_P = $(shell ./constants "SIZEOF_VOID_P"))
        $(eval FOOBAR = $(shell ./constants "FOOBAR"))

main: pre-build
        @echo $(SIZEOF_VOID_P) $(FOOBAR)
```

With the program `constants` being something in the line of

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ALL CHECKS AND BALANCES OMITTED!

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s constant_to_test\n",argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // good for a couple of constants but should be changed
  // to a proper parser if you have more than a dozen or so
  if(strncmp(argv[1], "SIZEOF_VOID_P", 13 ) == 0){
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(void *));
  }
  else if (strncmp(argv[1], "FOOBAR", 6) == 0){
    printf("%d\n",42);
  }
  // ...
  else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Constant %s unknown\n",argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It is by far not the most elegant solution but it works well if all you need are some constants. On the other side: it will quickly get rather nasty for more complicated things e.g.: to find the path to the right compiler and call it with the correct arguments, find the path to some libraries and check if they are the right ones, and so on and so forth.

Comment: That Makefile wouldn't work, as `SIZEOF_VOID_P = $(shell ./constants SIZEOF_VOID_P)` is part of a recipe, and thus would not persist over  rules...   You would need an `eval` to set the variable...

Comment: @John the makefile works as it is, but you're right, of course, it works *only* as it is and as tested with GNU make version 3.81. Do you think your comment is enough or should I weave that information into my answer and/or change the example? But I'll wait another couple of hours for the unlikely chance that the OP gives some feedback and more needs to be changed/adapted.

Comment: I just tried it (with make 3.81), and got `make: SIZEOF_VOID_P: Command not found`.   I might update it to use eval.

Comment: @John yepp, me too. Now! I swear it worked yesterday! What the...? C&P error? Oh my, how embarassing! *sigh* Changed to `eval` and put some quotes around the arguments to the helper program `constants`. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to trash the existing makefiles (which I fear may cause more problems than it solves). I just want to add appropriate some defines to them.
>
> Is there a nice why do to this?

If you're prepared to assume GNU make, then you can rely on its `include` directive to include Makefile fragments from external files into your existing Makefiles.  You could modify the existing Makefiles to add one or more `include` directives at or near the top in place of the section(s) that need to be adjusted to adapt to the build environment.  Then write a program to analyze the system and output the appropriate Make variable definitions into the appropriate file.  The `include` directive is not a standard feature of POSIX `make`, however, so it may not be a viable option.

---

Alternatively, `make` variable definitions can be specified on the command line.  For example,

```
make all SIZEOF_VOID_P=8
```

In principle, then, you could set all the make variables you need by invoking `make` via a wrapper script that provides the definitions in this way.  Such a script might determine the needed values dynamically, or you might generate the script via a separate configuration program.  Either way, you would probably need to modify the existing Makefiles to suppress (re)definition of the variables involved.